Migrate data from local PostgreSQL to cloud-hosted
What is a simple and reliable way to migrate database data from a locally hosted solution to a cloud-hosted where all I have is a way to connect to the DB without access to the raw files themselves? I could simply recreate all tables, indexes, functions, triggers, and then insert all data, but is there a simpler way to just move an exact copy of the data, maybe from a backup file?
